# Qiskit - CircuitError Index 1 out of range for size 1

Tags: qiskit

Below Qiskit snippet throws error - `CircuitError: 'Index 1 out of range for size 1.`. What's wrong?

```
import qiskit
number_of_qubits = 1 
initial_state = [0,1]
qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(number_of_qubits)
qc.initialize(initial_state)
qc.x(initial_state)
qc.draw()
```

Error trace:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\my_custom_virtualenvs\qiskit_env\lib\site-packages\qiskit\circuit\quantumcircuit.py:4939, in _bit_argument_conversion_scalar(specifier, bit_sequence, bit_set, type_)
   4938 try:
-> 4939     return bit_sequence[specifier]
   4940 except IndexError as ex:

IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

CircuitError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 6>()
      4 qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(number_of_qubits)
      5 qc.initialize(initial_state[1])
----> 6 qc.x(initial_state)
      7 qc.draw()

...
CircuitError: 'Index 1 out of range for size 1.'

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `X` to two qubits, `[0,1]`. However, your circuit has only one. You can change your code to:

```
import qiskit
number_of_qubits = 1
initial_state = [0,1]
qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(number_of_qubits)
qc.initialize(initial_state)
qc.x(0)
qc.draw()
```

```
   ┌─────────────────┐┌───┐
q: ┤ Initialize(0,1) ├┤ X ├
   └─────────────────┘└───┘
```